# How do I make material textures visible in the Render window?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

Okay so I've made a blender model, added textures and recently I've started adding materials but now the textures aren't showing up the same as what I'm seeing in the 3D window.

Blender Default Window:
[image: Screenshot and model property of CraftyMaelyss]

Rendered:
[image: Screenshot and model property of CraftyMaelyss]

Comparison:
[image: Screenshot and model property of CraftyMaelyss]

I know that I need to assign a texture to a material, which I have done but it's still not showing up how I want it to.

I'm not a pro at Blender but I wouldn't consider myself a beginner, so if anyone can provide screenshots with their instructions(such as checking boxes or settings) I would greatly appreciate it :)

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

***Also by request, I cannot upload or share this model, sorry :(***

@Dimali I believe so, here's a screenshot of it:
[image: Screenshot and model property of CraftyMaelyss]

@Dimali And here's a screenshot of the settings:
[image: Screenshot and model property of CraftyMaelyss]

Comment: Does the texture have the image assigned that you have UV unwrapped?

Comment: @Dimali I believe so, I've added a screenshot of it to the question, since I can't find an option to add a screenshot in my reply comment.

Comment: Ok. What are your settings in the "Mapping" Section of the texture? Coordinates: UV?

Comment: @Dimali I've added another screenshot of the settings if that helps :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by default window and rendered in the first two images. Are you wanting to get the eye textures back in your 3D view?

Comment: I assume you did not mix up the following: "Rendering" is what you do when you click "Render" -> "Render Image" (=F12). You can activate or deactivate textured preview in your viewport by using textured view or solid view with or without "texture solid". Your second image is showing the viewport with deactivated textures, the comparison image is done by using viewport (left image) and rendering as in pressing F12 (right image), correct?

Comment: Am I mistaken or are you viewing in "Solid Mode"?  Looks like it in the pics.  At bottom, click on the little white ball and select "Material Mode".

Comment: @Dimali That's right, that's what I did. Also with the second screenshot, I was showing the materials weren't showing the textures that were assigned to them correctly.

They do show up when rendered, however it still looks very different compared to the 3D viewport with the textured shading on.

Comment: @LetTheWritersWrite What I'm trying to do is to get the rendered model to look the same as it does in the 3D viewport with the textures on.

When I render the model, it looks very off and not at all like it's appearance in the 3D viewport, which is the issue.

Comment: @Edgel3D That makes the model in the default window look like the rendered version(which is a really cool tip for the future, thank you :D) What I want to do is make the rendered model look like the default version.

See the third screenshot with the default and the rendered comparison? I want the rendered model to look like the default, since it looks very weird when rendered.

Comment: Turning off specular or reducing specular intensity will get rid of the highlights that don't appear in the viewport. As for your texture problem, I'm not sure what the reason is.

Comment: I don't generally use the textured view for this reason.  The "material" mode represents how things will look with OpenGL rendering and also Blender Render.   Good luck with that.  A screenshot would at least capture what you're seeing, albeit a poor one.